# GRPC: how to open GRPC profiling macro GPR_TIMER_BEGIN/GPR_TIMER_END

Tags: c++, grpc

We're using GRPC to sending message that met performance issues. We found there're lots of GPR_TIMER_BEGIN/GPR_TIMER_END in most critical path to measure time consuming of the functions.

But just define GRPC_STAP_PROFILER in Makefile would trigger build errors.

Anyone who knows how to open the GRPC's performance profiling macros?

Answer (score 3):

The stap profiler hasn't been properly maintained unfortunately. You'd get more chance with the basic profiler. No need to update the Makefile, you can simply run `make CONFIG=basicprof`.

Most of our profiling however nowadays happens using microbenchmarks. You can browse the [directory with our microbenchmarks](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/test/cpp/microbenchmarks), which are actively used to create automated github comments to notify us of performance differences caused by pull requests.

Comment: Do you need to do anything else to get the profile generated? I rebuilt grpc with CONFIG=basicprof, set LATENCY_TRACE in the environment but no profile was generated (in a C++ app, grpc is linked in statically)